# UITableView loads cells before API call is completed

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous, networking

I am working on this app that helps me run some NLP on tweets & display results in a feed using a `TableView`.

Up to today, my app was running all the NLP on-device with a custom model built with `CreateML` & Apple's `NaturalLanguage` framework. When I would open the app, the tweets would be analyzed & show the results in the feed.

To increase the accuracy of results, I set up my own API & now make a call to that API to do some extra analysis. The issue now is that when I open the app, there is some kind of race condition. The feed does not show anything until I refresh. In the console, I see that the feed is done running `fetchAndAnalyze()` that gets the results while the API call in `tripleCheckSentiment()` is not completed.

Here is some explanation around the architecture.

**NetworkingAPI (only the relevant code):**

```
// This function makes a call to the Twitter API & returns a JSON of a user's tweets.
static func getUserTimeline(screenName: String, completion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
   client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
     if connectionError != nil {
        print("Error: \(connectionError)")
     }
     do {
        let json = try JSON(data: data!)
        completion(json)
     } catch let jsonError as NSError {
        print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
     }
   }
}

// This function makes a call to my API & checks the sentiment of a Tweet. 
static func checkNegativeSentiment(tweet: Tweet, completion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
   let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
   AF.request(apiURL, method: .post, parameters: tweet, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).response {
     response in
     do {
        let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
        completion(json)
     } catch let jsonError as NSError {
        print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
        completion(JSON.init(parseJSON: "API OFFLINE."))
     }
   }
}
```

**TweetManager (only the relevant code):**

```
// This function is called from the app's feed to retrieve the most recent tweets. 
func fetchTweets(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
   for friend in Common.listOfFriends {
     NetworkingAPI.getUserTimeline(screenName: friend.handle, completion: {
        success in
        self.parseTweets() // This puts all the tweets returned in success in a list.
        self.analyze()    // Runs some NLP on the tweets. 
        completion(true)
     })
   }
}

func analyze() {
   for tweet in listOfTweets {
     // Does some on-device NLP using a model created with CreateML ...
     if sentimentScore == "0" {  // That is the tweet is negative. 
        doubleCheckSentiment(tweet: tweet)
     }
   }
}

func doubleCheckSentiment(tweet: Tweet) {
   // Does some on-device NLP using Apple's generic framework NaturalLanguage. 
   if sentimentScore <= -0.8 {   // Once again, the tweet is negative.
     tripleCheckSentiment(tweet: tweet)
   }
}

func tripleCheckSentiment(tweet: Tweet) {
   NetworkingAPI.checkNegativeAzureSentiment(tweet: tweet, completion: {
     json in
     if json["value"]["sentiment"].int! == 2 {  // We confirm the tweet is negative.
        Common.negativeTweets.append(tweet)
     }
   }
}
```

**FeedVC (only the relevant code):**

```
// This function gets called when the view appears & at a bunch of different occasions.
func fetchAndAnalyze() {
   var friendsAnalyzed = 0
   tweetManager.fetchTweets(completion: {
     success in
     friendsAnalyzed += 1  // Every time completion hits, it means one friend was analyzed. 
     if friendsAnalyzed == Common.listOfFriends.count {  // Done analyzing all friends.
        self.tableView.reloadData()    // Refresh & show the tweets in Common.negativeTweets in table. 
   }
}
```

I know this is long & I deeply apologize but if I could get some help on this, I would really appreciate it! By the way, excuse my use of @escaping & all that, I am fairly new to handling asynchronous API calls.

Thanks!

**EDIT, after implementing jawadAli's solution which works in some cases for some reason, I notice the following pattern: **

[image]

Imagine I add a friend to my listOfFriends. Then I refresh, which calls `fetchAndAnalyze()`. We see in the log `REFRESH CALLED.` & by the end of the function call that no negative tweets were found. Right after this happened, we get a result from our API call that one tweet was found negative.

If I refresh again, then that tweet is displayed. Any clue?

Comment: As far as i can see, you are calling `NetworkingAPI.getUserTimeline` multiple times (as count of listOfFriends) in `fetchTweets` function, bu you did not wait all the responses in completion.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk, yes! This is what I've understood & what seems to be causing the problem. I tried a bunch of different things, would you have a tip on how to approach this problem?

Comment: You can resolve it with [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

Comment: I tried it out the following way, @omerfarukozturk. 
`let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
for friend in Common.listOfFriends { 
   myGroup.enter()
   NetworkingAPI.getUserTimeline(screenName: friend.handle, completion: {
     succes in 
     self.parseTweets()
     self.analyze()
     count += 1
     if count == Common.listOfFriends.count { myGroup.leave() }
   })
  }
myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
   completion(true)
})`
It didn't work, sadly. When printing `count`, I'd get to the max before the API call prints its JSON.

Comment: You can update the question with your approach that you have tried so far. this will be more clear investigate.

Comment: btw, you need to call `leave()` in each completion, not only when `count == Common.listOfFriends.count`.

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with this function. On first transection of for loop your completion get fired ..

```
func fetchTweets(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
   for friend in Common.listOfFriends {
        myGroup.enter()
     NetworkingAPI.getUserTimeline(screenName: friend.handle, completion: {
        success in

       self.parseTweets() 
       self.analyze()  
       myGroup.leave()

     })
   }
}
 myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
      
        completion(true)
})
```

Also reload data on Main thread

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

NOTE: You need to handle success and failure case accordingly.. i am just giving an idea how to use dispatchGroup to sync calls ...

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot. I still need to understand how DispatchGroup works but this did the trick for me!

Comment: Hm, it's weird. It seems like if I have more than one friend in my list, it works fine. However, if I only have one, it still gives me the same issue.

Comment: it should not ... debug it to check whats happening

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit & tell me if you have any clue what is happening? This is what I was able to debug.